# For loop issue?

Tags: python

Given a list of numbers and a number k, return whether any two numbers from the list add up to k.
For example, given [10, 15, 3, 7] and k of 17, return true since 10 + 7 is 17.

```
n=0,
Axe= [10, 15, 3, 7],
uplimit=len(Axe)


for x in range(uplimit):
    print(Axe[n])
    print(Axe[x:uplimit])
    print (Axe[n]+ Axe[x])
```

i am stuck here. i can get the fist value to be added with the rest, but dont know how to get the rest to do the same.
I can do it manually of course but i need to automate the process

Comment: Have a look on leetcode Two Sum Problem, the very first question

Comment: Also see Stack Overflow guidance on [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  All you do in this problem is to print one set of sums: you have not addressed the two critical logic items in the assignment.  This suggests that you need help in problem analysis, which is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: See [How much research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).  Since this is a common coding exercise that is solved in many places on line, we expect you to find such resources and include that in your post.

Comment: it will need two `for`-loops to check every pair (every two numbers)

Answer (score 2):

This function should do the trick

```
def my_function(mylist, k):
    for i in range(len(mylist)):
        first = mylist[i]
        for second in mylist[i:]:
            print(f"{first} + {second} = {first+second}")
            if first+second ==k:
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: print(f"{first} + {second} = {first+second}")

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `itertools`:

```
import itertools

def sum_pairs(num_list, k):
    all_pairs  = list(itertools.combinations(num_list, 2))

    for pair in all_pairs:
        if sum(pair) == k:
            return True

    return False
```

You can then call the above function:

```
Axe = [10, 15, 3, 7]
k = 17
print(sum_pairs(Axe, k))
```

Comment: filter(lambda x: sum(x) == k , combinations(num_list,2))

Comment: Thanks, that's an elegant solution! I just want to mention that your proposal returns the pair (i.e. the tuple x) whose sum is equal to k.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [10, 15, 3, 7]
k = 17

for i in range(len(list)):
    temp = list[i]
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if (temp + list[i] == k ):
            print("true")
            return
```